# Disable console screen on Debian

Tags: debian

I am trying to disable the console screen on my Debian VM, so when I access it locally all I get is an blank screen.

I thought about removing / disabling the video drivers, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I suppose you mean the virtual terminals? (`tty1` etc.) Or something else? And you likely want to disable logins on them, and perhaps kernel boot messages too?

Comment: hay sorry  virtual terminals, i have disabled logins and looking at disabling the grub cmdline at the mo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian 8, running systemd, you can disable VTs running `getty` (which is what displays the login prompt) by editing [`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html):

```
[Login]
NAutoVTs=0
ReserveVT=0
```

This disables auto-VT-allocation and VT reservation.

You’ll also need to disable the first VT’s `getty`, managed by `autovt@`. Create a directory named `/etc/systemd/system/autovt@.service.d` containing a `disable.conf` file with the contents

```
[Unit]
ConditionKernelCommandLine=locallogin
```

This will disable the unit unless you add `locallogin` to the kernel’s boot parameters (so you can undo this behaviour if you ever need to).

Additionally, if you want to stop kernel messages from appearing on the consoles, you can run

```
dmesg -n 1
```

(*e.g.* in `/etc/rc.local`). Panics will still appear on the consoles, I don’t think that can be disabled.

On older versions of Debian, or Debian 8 running `sysvinit`, you can disable `getty` VTs by commenting all the lines mentioning `/sbin/getty` in `/etc/inittab`.

Comment: Can't you get rid of all kernel messages on virtual consoles by passing `console=ttyS0` or some other dummy device?

Answer (score -2):

Thanks I found i can do this also

```
/bin/systemctl --no-block disable getty@tty*.service
```

so i put in an for loop